# How to pass char pointer into opencl kernel?

Tags: opencl

I am trying to pass a char pointer into the kernel function of opencl as

```
char *rp=(char*)malloc(something);
ciErr=clSetKernelArg(ckKernel,0,sizeof(cl_char* ),(char *)&rp)
```

and my kernel is as

```
__kernel void subFilter(char *rp)
{
    do something
}
```

When I am running the kernel I am getting

```
error -48 in clsetkernelargs 1
```

Also, I tried to modify the kernel as

```
__kernel void subFilter(__global char *rp)
{
    do something
}
```

I got error as

```
error -38 in clsetkernelargs 1
```

which says invalid mem object .

i just want to access the memory location pointed by the rp in the kernel.
Any help would be of great help.

Thnaks, 
Piyush

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any arrays and memory objects that you use in an OpenCL kernel needed to be allocated via the OpenCL API (e.g. using `clCreateBuffer`). This is because the host and device don't always share the same physical memory. A pointer to data that is allocated on the host (via `malloc`) means absolutely nothing to a discrete GPU for example.

To pass an array of characters to an OpenCL kernel, you should write something along the lines of:

```
char *h_rp = (char*)malloc(length);
cl_mem d_rp = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, length, h_rp, &err);
err = clSetKernelArg(ckKernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &d_rp)
```

and declare the argument with the `__global` (or `__constant`) qualifier in your kernel. You can then copy the data back to the host with `clEnqueueReadBuffer`.

If you *do* know that host and device share the same physical memory, then you can allocate memory that is visible to both host and device by creating a buffer with the `CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR` flag, and using `clEnqueueMapMemObject` when you wish to access the data from the host. The new shared-virtual-memory (SVM) features of OpenCL 2.0 also improve the way that you can share buffers between host and device on unified-memory architectures.